# Renaming laravel validation array notation in error messages

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a very unfriendly field name in my validation errors similar to the array notation used as name for the field's rules
EG.

```
$rules = [
    'resource.*.name' => 'required|string|max:16'
];

// error message.
// the resource.0.name is required.
```

How do I rename the resource.0.name in the message to something else like name or resource name.

Answer (score 1):

For more convenience you may use laravels form request validation,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class Resource extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'resource.*.name' => 'required|string|max:16'
        ];
    }


    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'resource.*.name'     => 'The Resouce Name must match the criteria'
        ];
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\Resource;

public function store(Resource $request)
{

}
```